# find maximum value of a function involving factorials

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the maximum value of $\large \frac{35^n}{n!}$ for any positive integer $n$.
How I can solve this problem using calculus? Is there any other method to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 7):

**Question 1**: How can this question be solved using calculus?

If you must, differentiatie with respect to $n$. Not recommended though, bringing us to the next part.

**Question 2:** Are there any alternative methods?

Yes. Define $a_n =\frac{35^n}{n!}$

Now we must find the maximum among, $a_1, a_2, a_3....$

$a_1$ = 35
$a_2 = 35*35/2 = a_1*35/2$
$a_3=35*35*35/(3*2) = a_2*35/3$

It can be observed that $a_n = a_{n-1}*35/n$

Thus till $n=34$ a number greater than 1 is being multiplied always and the series is increasing. For $n=35$ 1 gets multiplied, not chaning the value. $n=36$ onwards the series decreases.

Thus the maximum is $35^{34}/34!$ = $35^{35}/35!$

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve it involves noticing that $${35^{35}\over35!}\gt{35^{36}\over36!}$$